# Variable is not initializer

Tags: listview, arraylist

Variable "listitme" is not initializer "new ArrayList<>()" is not redundant

```
class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    ArrayList<listitme> listitme = new ArrayList<>();
    ListAdapter(ArrayList<listitme> listitm){
        this.listitme =listitm;
```

i have problem in `new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: <listitme> here you should have type of elements in list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have done a small mistake, Try this:

```
ArrayList<listitme> listitme = new ArrayList<listitme>();
```

Here You need to have `ArrayList` of type `listitme` in second line.